# Python Numpy how to change the data types inside an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to calculate information from an array that contains integers, however when I do a calculation the results are foat's. How do I change the ndarry to accept 0.xxx numbers as a input. Currently I am only getting 0's. Here is the code I have been trying to get working:

```
        ham_fields = np.array([], dtype=float)   # dtype specifies the type of the elements
        ham_total = np.array([], dtype=float)  # dtype specifies the type of the elements
        ham_fields = data[data[:, 0] == 0]  # All the first column of the dataset doing a check if they are true or false
        ham_sum = np.delete((ham_fields.sum(0)),0)  # Boolean indices are treated as a mask of elements to remove none Ham items
        ham_total = np.sum(ham_sum)
        ham_len = len(ham_sum)



        for i in range(ham_len):
            ham_sum[i] = (ham_sum[i] + self.alpha) / (ham_total + (ham_len * self.alpha))
```

Comment: Your code is problematic. It seems you have sliced the main code without correcting it to be runnable. For example `self` which relate to a class definition. what is `data`?

Comment: Please show an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as properly formatted code in the question.

Comment: you're not specifying a dtype when you create ham_sum: `ham_sum = np.delete((ham_fields.sum(0)),0).astype(float)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ham_fields = np.array([], dtype=float)

ham_fields = data[data[:, 0] == 0] 
ham_sum = np.delete((ham_fields.sum(0)),0)
```

This line assigns a new array object to `ham_fields`.  The first assignment did nothing for you.  In Python variables are not declared at the start.

If `data` has a `int` dtype, then so does `ham_fields`.  You could change that with a another assignment

```
ham_fields = ham_fields.astype(float)
```

`ham_sum` has the same `dtype` as `ham_fields`, from which it's derived.

Assigning a float to an element of a `int` dtype array will not change the dtype.

```
    for i in range(ham_len):
        ham_sum[i] = (ham_sum[i] + self.alpha) / (ham_total + (ham_len * self.alpha))
```

If `self.alpha`, `ham_total` are scalar then you should be able to do

```
ham_sum = (ham_sum + self.alpha)/(ham_toal + (ham_len * self.alpha))
```

This makes a new array, which will be float, and assigns it to `ham_sum` variable.  It's a new assignment (not modification) so the float dtype is preserved.  Or to make things clear, assign it to a new variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use astype(int) to convert it to an int array after the calculation

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print(array1.dtype)
#output: int64

array2 = np.array([2, 3, 4])
print(array2.dtype)
#output: int64

array3 = array1 / array2
print(array3.dtype)
#output: float64

array4 = array3.astype(int)
print(array3.dtype)
#output: int64
```

You could also do that inside of your calculation by working with brackets:

```
array3 = (array1 / array2).astype(int)
```